# How to do "Client Authentification" if I'm not able to provide private key

Tags: c++, openssl, private-key, client-certificates

I want to set up my local server to communicate with my client. They build TLS connection using Openssl. I try to implement double side authentication, like server would verify client and client also needs to verify server.

When I use certificates generated by my self, everything works fine. The code is as following. It's C++ code in client. I set up client cert, private key and intermediate cert. In server side I saved a CA cert.

The relationship is: CA signs intermediate cert, intermediate cert signs client cert.

As we know, the reason that we need to provide client private key is the client will signature a "challenge" then send to server. Server could get client public key by certificate chain and use it to decode the encrypt "challenge" to see if they matched. You could see this link for detailed process:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#TLS_handshake

However in my scenario, I have no permission to get the private key. I only have an API to call, which takes the digest or anything we want to encode as input and return a string encoded by client private key.

Therefore I'm not able to pass any "ClientPrivateKeyFileTest" to TLS.

I searched openssl source code but all handshakes were done in this function: SSL_do_handshake() and I'm not allowed to modify this function.

```
// load client-side cert and key
SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file(m_ctx, ClientCertificateFileTest, SSL_FILETYPE_PEM);
SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file(m_ctx, ClientPrivateKeyFileTest, SSL_FILETYPE_PEM);

// load intermediate cert
X509* chaincert = X509_new();
BIO* bio_cert = BIO_new_file(SignerCertificateFileTest, "rb");
PEM_read_bio_X509(bio_cert, &chaincert, NULL, NULL);
SSL_CTX_add1_chain_cert(m_ctx, chaincert)

m_ssl = SSL_new(m_ctx);

// get_seocket is my own API
m_sock = get_socket();

SSL_set_fd(m_ssl, m_sock)

// doing handshake and build connection
auto r = SSL_connect(m_ssl);
```

I think all handshake processes would be done after I call SSL_connect(). So I wonder is there other way I can do to complete the client-authentication?

For example, I could skip adding private key step but set up a callback function somewhere which can handle all cases when SSL needs to use private key to calculate something.

PS: The API is a black box in the client machine.

> One more thing, these days I found that openssl engine may help this problem. But does anybody know what kind of engine is useful for this problem? The EC sign, verification or others?
>
> Final update: I implemented a OpenSSL engine to reload EC_KEY_METHOD so that I'm able to use my own sign function.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: It is necessary to have the private key in order to affirm the authenticity of the corresponding public key. This is a fundamental aspect of asymetric public-key cryptography. Based on your description, it looks like OpenSSL simply has no means of supporting the security model where it executes a callback to encrypt something using a particular public key, with your code acting as a proxy to an external service that does the encryption. I don't think GnuTLS does this, either. This seems to be a somewhat unorthodox implementation of PK, that modern libraries do not support.

Comment: Please tell us more about the API to access the private key.  Is that a "black box" that runs on the client machine, or is it a web endpoint on a separate server?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Thanks for your comment! You are correct. Pub-key and private-key is significant in asymmetric cryptography. Actually this is a common OpenSSL client code, which loads client certificate and private key for authenticating. And the API I said is also using the private key to encrypt input message. However the reason I cannot use private key directly is the client product is from other factories so they would not provide me any private key due to security problem.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik What I have is the API to encode a challenge, which will be encoded by private key in somewhere. So I'm looking if there is a way to tell TLS how to encode messages, random numbers or challenges using that API instead of private key directly.

Comment: @dgnuff It's a black box in the client machine.

Comment: The supposed security is an illusion.  If you've got the "black box" on the client machine, then you already have the private key on the machine, just in an obscured format, and as one of the basic truths of security states: "Security through obscurity is not security".  In particular, if a client machine is compromised (i.e. stolen) you might as well consider the private key compromised.  Either the hackers can use the black box to gain access to the private key, or they can actually binary dump the black box (or a memory image of it running), and extract the key from that.

Comment: Adding to the above, OpenSSL already has all the mechanisms in place to make such a black box unnecessary.  A far better and far simpler solution is to apply a form of 2FA to the private key and put a passphrase on it that only the authorized user knows.  About the only thing that'll break that is "rubber hose cryptography" which will generally break any protection you might have.  Lose the machine in a situation like that and no damage is done because the hackers can't get into the private key in the first place.  Revoke it just to be sure, but there isn't a useful attack surface there.

Comment: @JinXie Final comment.  I'm not trying to convince you personally, this is more for the policy makers in your company to read and understand.

Comment: @dgnuff You raise an interested point! Thank you very much I will discuss this point with makers as well.

Comment: @dgnuff One more comment, I guess this kind of "black box" is still useful like ATECC608A. It store all secret data including private key.